# What is the meaning of 또 만나요?

Tags: translation, greeting, examples

I've the following simple sentence: "저는 로한이에요. 또 만나요".
Which is supposed to mean " I am Rohan. See you again".

Many tutorials specifically translates "또 만나요" as "see you again". The sentence is a bit not natural to me in its english translation. Is it supposed to be a goodbye of the form "See you later" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is goodbye of the form "See you later".
However, It is awkward to say "또 만나요" to others because it sounds we *have to* meet again. We use "다음에 봐요" rather than "또 만나요". I am not native English speaker but I have heard "see you around" and "see you later" which sounds more natural than "see again".
"또 만나요" is barely used in modern conversation. Usage of "또 만나요" is marginal.
I have seen "또 만나요" in literature written in 20C.